# How mahout's recommendation evaluator works

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

Can anyone tell me how does mahout's RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator work? More specifically how it randomly splits training and testing data and what data the result is compare against? Based on my understating, you need some sort of ideal/expected result which you need to compare against actual result from the recommendation algorithm to find out TP or FP
and thus compute precision or recall. But it looks like mahout provides a precision/recall score without that ideal/result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data is split into training and testing set using some relevance threshold value which you supply in the `evaluate` method of the `RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator` class. If this values is `null` there is method that computes it (`computeThreshold`). The class that splits the data into training and testing is `GenericRelevantItemsDataSplitter`. If you take a look into the code you can see that first the preferences for each user are sorted according the the value in descending order, and than only those that have value bigger than the `relevanceThreshold` are taken as relevant. Also notice that at most `at` are put into this set.

```
@Override
  public FastIDSet getRelevantItemsIDs(long userID,
                                       int at,
                                       double relevanceThreshold,
                                       DataModel dataModel) throws TasteException {
    PreferenceArray prefs = dataModel.getPreferencesFromUser(userID);
    FastIDSet relevantItemIDs = new FastIDSet(at);
    prefs.sortByValueReversed();
    for (int i = 0; i < prefs.length() && relevantItemIDs.size() < at; i++) {
      if (prefs.getValue(i) >= relevanceThreshold) {
        relevantItemIDs.add(prefs.getItemID(i));
      }
    }
    return relevantItemIDs;
  }
```

How the precision and the recall are computed you can see in the `RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator.evaluate` method. In short it is like this:
First only one user is evaluated at a time. His preference values are split into relevant (as described above) and other. The relevant ones are used as test set, and the other together with all other users as training. Then `top-at` recommendations are produced for this user. Next the method looks whether some of the items that were taken aside as test set appear in the recommendation, and how many:

```
int intersectionSize = 0;
      List<RecommendedItem> recommendedItems = recommender.recommend(userID, at, rescorer);
      for (RecommendedItem recommendedItem : recommendedItems) {
        if (relevantItemIDs.contains(recommendedItem.getItemID())) {
          intersectionSize++;
        }
  }
```

The precision than is computed as follows:

```
(double) intersectionSize / (double) numRecommendedItems
```

Where `numRecommendedItems` is usually your `at` if the recommender produces at least `at` recommendations, otherwise smaller.

Similar, the recall is computed as follows:

```
(double) intersectionSize / (double) numRelevantItems
```

where `numRelevantItems` is the number of items in the test set for this user.

The final precision and recall are macro  average of all precisions and recalls for all users.

Hope this answers your question.

**EDIT:** To continue with your question, it is very tricky when evaluating IR statistics (precision and recall) for recommender systems, especially if you have small number of user preferences per user. In this [book](http://www.cs.bme.hu/nagyadat/Recommender_systems_handbook.pdf) you can find very useful insights. It says that

> it is  typically assumed that the not liked items would have not been
>   liked even if they had been recommended  i.e they are uninteresting or useless for the user. However, this may not be true, because the set of not liked items may contains some interesting items that the user did not select. For example, a user may not have liked an item because he was unaware of its existence, but after the recommendation exposed that item, the user can decide to select it. In any case when using IR statistics, the number of the FP is over estimated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I hope i can repay your help some day.